# Apache Solr More Like This: How does the mlt.minwl parameter affect query results

Tags: php, drupal, search, solr

The [Apache Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) states that mlt.minwl =
minimum word length below which words will be ignored.

A concrete example of this is appreciated.

Example query (decoded)

(string:822) qt=mlt&fl=nid%2Ctitle%2Cpath%2Curl%2Css_simple_geo_position%2Cis_cck_field_sponsored_content_yn%2Cis_cck_field_compound_review_yn%2Cis_workflow_state%2Cds_cck_field_publish_date%2Cds_cck_field_publish_expiration_date%2Csm_timeout_search_event_type%2Csm_timeout_search_event_genre%2Csm_timeout_search_venue_type%2Csm_timeout_search_venue_feature%2Csm_timeout_search_venue_genre&mlt.fl=body%2Cname%2Ctaxonomy_names%2Ctitle&mlt.mintf=1&mlt.mindf=1&mlt.minwl=3&mlt.maxwl=15&mlt.maxqt=20&fq%5B0%5D=-is_cck_field_exclude_from_search%3A1&fq%5B1%5D=-type%3Aimage&fq%5B2%5D=-type%3Aoccurrence&fq%5B3%5D=%28nodeaccess_f98a254002c9_all%3A0+OR+nodeaccess_f98a254002c9_workflow_access%3A1+OR+nodeaccess_f98a254002c9_workflow_access_owner%3A0+OR+nodeaccess_all%3A0%29&facet.limit=21&version=1.2&wt=json&json.nl=map&q=milk&start=0&rows=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an "interesting term" (alike), found by MLT, has less than mlt.minwl number of characters it will be ignored (excluded from MLT results).
Default value of this param is 0, which means that the param has no effect.

> The essences of the internal workings
>   of MLT operate like this:
>
> 1. Gather all of the terms with frequency information from the input
>      document:
> 2. If the input document is a reference to a document within the
>      index, then loop over the fields
>      listed in mlt.fl, and then the term
>      information needed is readily there
>      for the taking, if the field has the
>      termVectors enabled. Otherwise get the
>      stored text, and re-analyze it to
>      derive the terms. If the input
>      document is posted as text to the
>      handler, then analyze it to derive the
>      terms. The analysis used is that
>      configured for the first field listed
>      in mlt.fl.
> 3. **Filter the "interesting terms" based on configured thresholds, one of which is your mlt.minwl param**.
> 4. Construct a query with these interesting terms across all of the
>      fields listed in mlt.fl.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what will be matched versus what will not? For example, compare the contents of two "title" fields in two documents. In the case of my query, it is set to 1, so I don't know how it is affecting results, and the wiki doesn't present a concrete example.

Comment: Since the min length is set to 1, it has no effect whatsoever. If you set it to e.g. **5**, the word **tree** will be excluded, because it has 4 characters. That's it, couldn't be simpler.